# How can we write ios mobile application in react native using windows 10 operation system?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am new in React Native world and I am trying to create an ios app using my windows 10 operating system, I see some blogs which says you can create by installing virtual machine and following some steps but I am looking if there is more simple way to do it ).

Comment: Whatever you do you will need Xcode to sign and build the application. Which requires you to have MacOS. Your best bet is to install a VM but this is dodgy ground legally so I’m not sure about that. Or buy yourself a Mac.

Comment: Fogmeister thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.